# batch file return does not make sense

Tags: php, batch-file

I have a batch file (`batch.bat`) with a simple echo.

```
`ECHO Hello world`
```

Then I use php to capture the output, But the output is not what I expected.

```
C:\wamp\www\postEnginInstruction>ECHO Hello world Hello world
```

Why do I not only get the `Hello world`?

**PHP**

```
     $output = shell_exec('batch.bat');
     print_r($output);
```

Comment: How are you executing this and showing the output in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
@ECHO Hello world
```

It seams PHP is also capturing commands. It is normal in long batch files to do:

```
@ECHO OFF
...
```

So commands are not displayed, just outputs.